# PHP SOAP call fail, header sending issue

Tags: php, soap

I need to make a soap call "GetCommitQueueData" with value 1234
I need to make auth to bypass HTTP auth
also I need to pass username, password and an id within the header but everytime it tells me id not send, here is my code maybe somebody can help:

```
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypass';  
$idi = "3445-343534-453453-343-344"; 
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', false);
$client = new SoapClient("https://localhost.com/myfile.wsdl", array('trace' => 1, 'login'    => 'myuser',
        'password' => 'mypass', 'Request-Id' => $idi));



$ns = 'http://foreignhost.com/AdminAPI_Admin'; //Namespace of the WS. 

//Body of the Soap Header. 
$headerbody = array('UserName' => $username, 
                    'Password' => $password, 
                    'Request-Id'=>$idi); 

$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'RequestorCredentials', $headerbody);        

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header); 


show($client->__getFunctions()); 

$info = $client->__soapCall("GetCommitQueueData", array('1234' ));
show($info); 



function show($data){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data); 
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] Missing Request-Id in headers

if there is an easier solution with nusoap let me know